# How accessible is 'Fullmetal Alchemist: The Sacred Star of Milos'?

Tags: fullmetal-alchemist

I love the *Fullmetal Alchemist* series. I've seen all of the original anime series, and the first movie. I haven't seen *Brotherhood* yet because my wife isn't all that interested.

Without resorting to spoilers, If I take her to see the second movie, will she be confused because she hasn't seen much? Is it all action? How much inter-personal relationships are covered?

Comment: Brotherhood is much closer to the manga and well worth you time.  While I love the original, Brotherhood is better in all aspects.

Comment: @Sardathrion Oh, I'm really looking forward to watching brotherhood, but my wife isn't, so it's lower priority.

Answer (score 2):

According to [that review](https://www.bateszi.me/2011/09/28/feast-or-filler-full-metal-alchemist-the-sacred-star-of-milos/), you should be able to follow it without having seen *Brotherhood*, since it focuses mostly on new characters, and takes place midway through *Brotherhood*.  However, I haven't seen the movie, so I can't say for certain.

The Greed arc is roughly where the the original anime and *Brotherhood* diverge.  So even without seeing *Brotherhood*, there's some backstory that will be familiar.

Comment: While this is helpful information, it doesn't actually answer my questions. My wife hasn't seen any FMA (sans the first episode that she didn't really like). How will she fare in the movie?

Comment: @McKay Sorry, I missed that part.  Until someone else who has seen the movie/has a better review answers, I'd guess she'd be quite confused - Why is Al a suit of armor?  Why does Ed have automail?  _What_ is automail, if they talk about it without actually showing it?  How does alchemy differ from magic?  Etc, Etc...

Comment: The TV show raises the same questions in the first episode. It eventually answers them, but I would guess that those particular points aren't a concern?